# X is a metric space. Y is a closed subset of X such that the distance between any two points in Y is at most 1.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I came across this question in an exam I appeared . The question is as follows :- 
$X$ is a metric space. $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$ such that the distance
between any two points in $Y$ is at most $1$.

We have to choose one correct answer from four options. The options are :-

A. $Y$ is compact

B. any continuous function from $Y$ → $\mathbb R$ is bounded

C. $Y$ is not an open subset of $X$

D. none of the above.

The answer given is none of the above but I don't see how.

I think answer is B. Please point out if my approach is flawed.
u
Consider a continuous function $f$ :  $Y$ → $\mathbb R$ .Consider a point $y_1$ $\epsilon$ $Y$ . Distance between any two points in $Y$ is at most $1$. Given any point $y$ in $Y$ , it lies in a neighborhood of $y_1$ which is of radius less than $2$. By continuity there exists a $\delta > 0 $ such that |$f(y) - f(y_1)$| < $\delta$ . Thus , all $f(y)$s are located within an interval of length $\delta$ from $f(y_1)$ and hence $f$ is bounded provided it is continuous. I felt it need not even be continuous everywhere but just at one point that would also imply boundedness. I don't see why this answer is wrong. I  thought of an example $Y = [0,1]$ and $f(y) = 1/y$  this one is not bounded , but then its undefined for $y = 0$ so we can't consider it to refute B.

I also would like to know why other options are incorrect. I couldn't analyse A properly. I could eliminate c though. Here's my attempt, is it correct. Consider $X$ to be subset of $\mathbb R$ , where $X = [0,1]$ . Consider $Y = X$. Then $Y$ is closed since it contains all its limit points and $Y$ is open relative to X as we can express $Y = (-1,2) \bigcap \mathbb R$ and $(-1,2)$ is open in $\mathbb R$.

Thanks.

Comment: B) Stolen from you: choose $X=(0,1]$, $Y=X$. Then $f(y):=y^{-1}$ is continuous and unbounded.
A) For example $X=L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $Y$ the ball with radius $1/2$ contradicts this.
C) Same as in $B$

Comment: You got continuity quite wrong (there is no such $\delta$). And why can't we take $X=Y=(0,1)$ to see that A,B,C are wrong?

Comment: Thanks for replying . I guess I need some time to understand it . Possibly after I have studied functional analysis. I will try to understand it though . Can you also point out why my approach is flawed. I used much of the intuition of the Reals in it. But then while dealing with Y I didnt assume anything about the metric. I thought it was general. But I guess there is something about functional spaces. Thanks.

Comment: @ Blah I will think over what you pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use $Y=(0,1]\subset X=(0,1]$ as a counterexample for all three, where in B you take $f(x)=1/x$.

In your attempt to address B you are using continuity in the wrong way. Actually, you are not using that $f$ is continuous, but rather that it is bounded, which of course defeats the purpose.

Comment: It seems that the issue might have been rather: $X=(0,1]$ and $Y=X$

Comment: Of course M.Luethi is right. Any space is closed in itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I understood it using the example of (0,1]. But could you point out where this statement in its own is wrong :- "By continuity there exists a δ>0 such that |f(y)−f(y1)| < δ ."     Also one more confirmation , (0,1] contains all its limit points hence it is closed. We can't consider 0 as it's limit point because since X doesn't have 0 in it there is no point considering 0 at all.

Comment: ohh. I think I understood where I got the continuity statement wrong. In continuity it is for all epsilon in the function range there exists a delta in the domain. I took it the other way around. Isnt it? Thanks for all the answers and comments  , now I am more clear than before on the topic both of continuity and metric spaces.